# Como reutilizar uma função corretamente em C?

Tags: c, funções

Eu tenho as seguintes funções :

```
int divisibilidade3(int num);
int divisibilidade9(int num);
int testarDivisibilidade(int dividendo, int divisor);
```

Com a função `testarDivisibilidade` eu vou testar todas as funções, se elas retornam `true` ou `false`. Mas o meu problema é que eu preciso reutilizar a função `divisibilidade3` dentro da função `divisibilidade9`, pois preciso verificar se um número é ou não, divisível por 9. Mas para ser divisível por 9, precisa ser divisível 2 vezes por 3.

**Código :**

```
int divisibilidade3(int num) {

int res = 0;

while( num > 0 )
{
    res += num % 10;
    num /= 10;
}

if(res > 9)
    return divisibilidade3(res);
else
    return ! (res % 3);


}

int divisibilidade9(int num) {
    if(divisibilidade3(num) == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Tenho certeza que a sintaxe esta errada dentro do `if-else` da função `divisibilidade9`, mesmo não dando erro na compilação, mas eu quero saber como que eu posso fazer para reutilizar 2 vezes a mesma função dentro do `if` para fazer a verificação.

**OBS : Estou fazendo varias perguntas separadas sobre o mesmo exercício pois se colocar tudo numa mesma pergunta, as minhas dúvidas sobre o assunto irão ficar confusas. Caso eu estiver fazendo algo errado, por favor me fale.**

Comment: Sinceramente esta sua função divisibilidade9 matematicamente não tem o menor sentido.

Comment: @Anonimo Eu sei que esta errada, o problema é que de acordo com o exercício eu tenho que fazer desta forma. Eu tenho que reutilizar a função divisibilidade3 dentro da função divisibilidade9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se as funções de divisibilidade *precisam* retornar verdadeiro e falso, então realmente não dá para retornar alguma informação que permita que você verifique o número por 9.  Mas tem um truque:

```
int
divisibilidade9(int num) {
    // "guard expression": se não for divisível por 3, pare já
    if (! divisibilidade3(num)) return 0;
    // Se chegou aqui, é divisível por 3; então veja se o
    // QUOCIENTE da divisão por 3 também é divisível por 3
    return divisibilidade3(num/3);
}
```

Ou seja, uma vez que você estabelece (via chamada à `divisibilidade3` que o número é divisível por 3, então você pode perfeitamente bem dividi-lo por 3. Se esse terço *também* for divisível por 3, então o número original é divisível por 9...

Comment: Novamente, você me ajudou, muito obrigado.